# How can I deal with failures when connecting to a MySQL cluster?

Tags: mysql, php, high-availability

Our company has created two MySQL servers that are kept in synch using a master-master strategy. The two-machine cluster is managed using [crmsh](http://www.nongnu.org/crmsh/). This is only a high-availability cluster, meaning that one MySQL server is being sent data at a time, and the other is only kept for backup if one server fails.

To test our cluster (I haven't done this sort of thing before), I wrote a script that will write 100000 rows into a table in a database. While this script is running, I log in to the server that is receiving the data (I.E. the server that the shared IP is pointing to) and reboot it, trying to simulate a hardware failure.

In some cases, the script keeps running. In some other cases, however, I receive the infamous `PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away` exception, or the `PDOException: SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction` exception, and so on.

How can I deal with these errors? I feel like there's a simple fact about programming for a cluster of servers that I'm unaware of.

Comment: Catch the exception in your application, log it, and then deal gracefully with it, retrying your connection.

Answer (score -1):

Each error message translates disparate meaning here

**For [MySQL server has gone away](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/gone-away.html)**

Mostly happens because the server timed out and connection is closed.
Increase `max_allowed_packet` in my.cnf to a larger value, restart MySQL and check

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet = 32M
```

---

**For [Deadlock](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-deadlocks.html)**

Mostly happens because multiple transactions together hold and request for locks, creating a dependency. It will be helpful if you post the query as well. Try to catch the exact reason

```
mysql> SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G;
```

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596005/working-around-mysql-error-deadlock-found-when-trying-to-get-lock-try-restarti) may also prove thoughtful